# Server selection in krb5.conf

Tags: active-directory, redhat, kerberos

i have a general question about the Kerberos configuration (krb5.conf) on a client.

If I give a RHEL8 client multiple AD servers for authentication (one in USA, one in Europe and one in Asia), which server would the client use if I want to connect from Germany?

krb5.conf

```
        AD.COMPANY.COM = {
        kdc = us-server.ad.company.com
        kdc = eu-server.ad.company.com
        kdc = asia-server.ad.company.com
        }
```

is the server list processed dull from top to bottom or is the server used which answers fastest?

Greetings
D1Ck3n

Comment: I've added more detail to my answer. If this answers your question, please mark it as such, otherwise please let us know if any.

Comment: Looks like T-Heron's answer was correct, and it was posted several days ago.  You should mark this as answered.

Comment: You don't seem to respond to comments and answers.  That's not the way this site is supposed to work.   -1 on the question.

Answer (score -2):

To elaborate on T-Herons answer up top, it would be a bit of a security vulnerability if it responded to the quickest one. Imagine I knew that one of the three servers stored a password in a way that an invalid hash would pass, I could slow the other two via a packet flood or DDOS and force the vulnerable server to respond first every time.

Design flaws like this can be generally exploited in most computer systems, (especially things like networking, for instance). So it's 'safe' to assume that in any instance dealing with authentication that you are are dealing with one authentication at a time.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! It all makes sense!

i'm asking this because i'm currently working on an Ansible Playbook that should join an iDM via ipa Role and then login to the nearest AD server nearby.

Comment: To be sure, the Kerberos-aware client will search for the location of a KDC via DNS SRV _kerberos records in the absence of KDCs being explicitly defined within the krb5.conf.  But any KDC listed in krb5.conf will take precedence over DNS SRV records.

Comment: I believe you can over come that using cache poisoning